# Is there a way I can store address of a string to a 2D character array

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, dynamic-memory-allocation, chararray

I am trying to make a program where it asks the user the number of shelves and number of positions on those shelves from the user then it asks the user where he wants to enter a product.
Now I got rows and columns figured out but I can't get the full product name printed it just shows a single character of said product. Is there a way I can store an address of a string variable and store it in that column of my row to print the complete word?
This is what I have done so far.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int M = 4;
    int N = 4;
    char *item;
    char ie[20];
    // dynamically create an array of pointers of size `M`
    char** A = new char*[M];

    // dynamically allocate memory of size `N` for each row
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        A[i] = new char[N];
    }
    cout << "Row num" << endl;
    int row = 0;
    cin >> row;
    cout << "Row col" << endl;
    int col = 0;
    cin >> col;
    //string temp;
    cout << "Item" << endl;
    cin >> ie;
    
        for (int j = 0; j < strlen(ie); j++)
        {
            A[row][col] = ie[j];
        }
    

    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            cout << A[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

}
```

sorry If the question is not clear or easy to understand.

Comment: Is there any reason why you cannot use `std::string`?

Comment: `std::vector<std::string> A(M);` -- Once you do that and use this, then all of those other issues go away.  -- *Is there a way i can store an address of a string variable* -- There are no string variables in the code you posted.  You have `char *`, and those are just pointers.  If you want a string type, then `std::string` is the string type.

Comment: `A[row][col]` is one character, which you assign `ie[j]` to multiple times. Its value after the loop is `ie[strlen(ie)-1]`.

Comment: `#include<string>` -- This defines `std::string`, but your code failed to use any of it.  The functions `strlen`, etc. are in `<cstring>`, not `<string>`

Answer (score 0):

First recommendation: **never** do like this

```
for (int j = 0; j < strlen(ie); j++) { /* do something */ }
```

Do it like this instead:

```
for (int i = 0; ie[i] != '\0'; ++i) { /* do something */ }
```

or

```
int ie_len = strlen(ie); 
for (int j = 0; j < ie_len; ++j) { /* do something */ }
```

because each loop condition check it calls `strlen` which takes length of string to calculate this function, so it takes **square** of string length in first case

I recommend use `std::string` and `std::vector` to store 2D array of strings, and avoid raw pointers and especially `new` operator (at least for code in question body you forgot `delete` for this new's). If you **really** want mess with raw pointers, see the end of this answer, but now recommended way to do what you want (as I understand what you want):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int M = 4;
    int N = 4;
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> A(M);
    char ie[20];
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        A[i] = std::vector<std::string>(N);
    }
    // can be used std::fill(A.begin(), A.end(), std::vector<std::string>(N)); instead for loop above but for loop simplier to understand
    cout << "Row num" << endl;
    int row = 0;
    cin >> row;
    cout << "Row col" << endl;
    int col = 0;
    cin >> col;
    string temp;
    cout << "Item" << endl;
    cin >> temp;

    A[row][col] = temp;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {
        cout << std::string(N * (temp.size() + 3) + 1, '-') << "\n"; // add separator to be clear what happening
        cout << "| "; // add separator to be clear what happening
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            A[i][j].resize(temp.size(), ' '); // for all columns has equal width to be clear what happening
            cout << A[i][j] << " | ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

example of input and output of this code:

```
Row num
1
Row col
2
Item
bob
-------------------------
|     |     |     |     | 
-------------------------
|     |     | bob |     | 
-------------------------
|     |     |     |     | 
-------------------------
|     |     |     |     |
```

Messing about `raw pointers` (your code with some editions and useful comments):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring> // cstring not string as @PaulMcKenzie mentioned in comments for strlen
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int M = 4;
    int N = 4;
    char *item;
    char ie[20];
    // dynamically create an array of pointers of size `M`
    const char*** A = new const char**[M]; // need add one more star because two for two-dimensonal array and one more for ~string~(aka char array)

    // dynamically allocate memory of size `N` for each row
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        A[i] = new const char*[N];
    }
    const char empty_string[1] = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < M; ++i){
        for (int j = 0; j < N; ++j){
            A[i][j] = empty_string; // make empty names on all shelves
        }
    }
    cout << "Row num" << endl;
    int row = 0;
    cin >> row;
    cout << "Row col" << endl;
    int col = 0;
    cin >> col;
    //string temp;
    cout << "Item" << endl;
    cin >> ie;
    
    /*not need this:
    for (int j = 0; j < strlen(ie); j++)
    {
        A[row][col] = ie[j];
    }
    just save adress like this:*/
    A[row][col] = ie;
    int ie_len = strlen(ie);

    /*  can be done simply:
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            cout << A[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    but it doesn't look like table*/
    // add seprators for understanding what happenning
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {
        // add horizontal separator
        for (int j = 0; j < N * (strlen(ie) + 3) + 1; ++j){
            cout << "-";
        }
        cout << "\n";
        cout << "| "; // add separator to be clear what happening
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            cout << A[i][j];
            // for equal width of columns add some spaces
            for (int k = strlen(A[i][j]); k < ie_len; ++k){
                cout << " ";
            }
            cout << " | ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    // not forget to delete all what u newed
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        delete A[i];
    }
    delete A;
}
```